# Cannot send null to state in order to make ImageField change to null in React and Django

Tags: reactjs, django, forms, image

## What I want to do

**Set null in `ImageField`. And I want to make the value of `ImageField` that a models has null.**

## Problem

When I send `Patch` request, I got an error like below.

```
The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.
```

Actually, I send image data as file which comes from `input type="file"`. When I send this request to set an image in a model, it works well. But when I send this request again to delete the image that the models has, it doesn't work.

How could I set null to `ImageField`? Or, how could I delete an image that a model already has?

I am a beginner to `React` and `Django` so I would like you to help me out.

I post my code related to my question below.

Thank you very much.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # AbstractUserでpasswordは定義済みのため、ここではpasswordを再定義しない(DBにはちゃんと保存される。)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    profile = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
    # AbstractUserはfirst_name,last_nameを保持しているため無効化
    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        ('staff status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            '管理サイトへのアクセス権を持っているかどうか'),
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        ('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            'ユーザーがアクティブかどうか'
        ),
    )

    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(
        ('superuser status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            'Designates that this user has all permissions without '
            'explicitly assigning them.'
        ),
    )
    # createdAt, updatedAt は時系列順等に並べたいモデルに付与
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ["username", "email"]

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

Serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
        write_only_fields = ('password')
        read_only_fields = ['id']

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if len(value) <= 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("ユーザーネームは5文字以上で入力してください")
        return value

    def validate_password(self, value):
        if len(value) <= 7:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("パスワードは最低8文字以上で入力してください")
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.get('password')
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(password)
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

User_Edit_Form.js

```
class User_Edit_Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: {
        username: this.props.loginUser.username,
        email: this.props.loginUser.email,
        profile: this.props.loginUser.profile,
        icon: this.props.loginUser.icon,
        background: this.props.loginUser.background,
      },
      //   Validation用
      // 　urlは必須項目ではないのでValidationには含めない
      message: {
        username: '',
        email: '',
      },
      loginUser: this.props.loginUser,
      imgUrls: {},
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleImageSelect = this.handleImageSelect.bind(this);
    this.cancelUploadedImage = this.cancelUploadedImage.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.setNoImage = this.setNoImage.bind(this);
  }

handleImageSelect = async (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const { info } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      info: { ...info, [name]: file },
    });
    console.log(this.state.info.icon);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.setState({ imgUrls: { ...this.state.imgUrls, [name]: reader.result } });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  setNoImage = async (target) => {
    await this.setState({ info: { ...this.state.info, [target]: null } });
  };

  cancelUploadedImage = async (target) => {
    await this.setState({ info: { ...this.state.info, [target]: this.props.loginUser.icon } });
    await this.setState({ imgUrls: { ...this.state.imgUrls, [target]: null } });
  };

handleSubmit = async () => {
    const data = new FormData();

    const deleteStringUrl = (key) => {
      if (typeof this.state.info[key] == 'string') {
        this.setState({ info: { ...this.state.info, [key]: 'noChangeImage' } });
      }
    };

    await deleteStringUrl('icon');
    await deleteStringUrl('background');


    Object.keys(this.state.info)
      // image, backgroundが変更されていない場合、それを取り除くためのfilter
      .filter((key) => this.state.info[key] !== 'noChangeImage')
      .map((filteredKey) => {
        data.append(filteredKey, this.state.info[filteredKey]);
        console.log(...data);
      });

    axios
      .patch(this.props.axiosUrl + 'user/' + this.props.loginUser.id + '/', data)
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    // history.push('/user/edit');
  };

render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <div>
              
        // omitted

        <div>
          <label>Icon</label>
          <input name="icon" type="file" onChange={this.handleImageSelect} />
          {this.state.imgUrls.icon != null ? (
            <>
              <Image src={this.state.imgUrls.icon} alt="" />
              {typeof this.state.info.icon == 'string' ? (
                <button name="icon" onClick={() => this.setNoImage('icon')}>
                  Set No Icon
                </button>
              ) : (
                <button name="icon" onClick={() => this.cancelUploadedImage('icon')}>
                  Cancel Upload Image
                </button>
              )}
            </>
          ) : (
            <Image src="" alt="" />
          )}
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Background</label>
          <input name="background" type="file" onChange={this.handleImageSelect} />
          {this.state.imgUrls.background != null ? (
            <>
              <Image src={this.state.imgUrls.background} alt="" />
              {typeof this.state.info.background == 'string' ? (
                <button name="background" onClick={() => this.setNoImage('background')}>
                  Set No Background
                </button>
              ) : (
                <button name="background" onClick={() => this.cancelUploadedImage('background')}>
                  Cancel Update Image
                </button>
              )}
            </>
          ) : (
            <Image src="" alt="" />
          )}
        </div>
```

==   ==    ==   ==    ==    ==
Edit

When I send the request to set null, my form data is like this.

```
Form Data

username: pear0319
email: e@t.com
profile: Kingsman
icon: null

// In this case, background isn't going to change so it's not in here.
```

Comment: Can you add the payload that receives in the Django end?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Thank you for your comment. I just add `Form Data` I send at the very bottom of my question. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send image field data like:

```
"image": ""
```

or

```
"image": null
```

If you want to set an image field as empty and set other fields you should not send image field (both key and value) and just send mandatory fields (like username or password) and only in this case you will be able to set an image field as empty (which is not set before). For deleting an existing image field from a model instance you can add another API, and since I don't know which type of `restframework`'s viewset you are using you can use something like following codes:

```
@action(detail=True, url_path='delete-avatar', methods=['delete'])
def delete_background(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
        Delete  user's background image.

    """
    user = self.get_object()
    user.background = ""
    user.save()
    return Response("Avatar image deleted successfully", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Which will add an action (with `DELETE` method) to your view and by calling this action you can delete an image field.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use `ModelViewSet`. Could I do what you taught me by overwriting `ModelViewSet` ?

Comment: Yeah, one way is to override delete method of your view (which is a child of ModelViewSet) and just write the code of action body which I mentioned before.

Comment: I added several actions to my `Viewset`, and then it works fine. Thank you very much. Honestly, I didn't come up with such a solution at all. Your advice helped me a lot. Thank you very much.